# (JavaFX) How to call method of class between constructor and initialize()?

Tags: java, reflection, javafx, interface, fxml

I have a class that implements an interface.  From my base class, I'm creating an instance of the implemented class like this:

```
Class newTab;
TransactionTabInterface tabInterface = null;
try {
  newTab = Class.forName("[package] + title);
  tabInterface = (TransactionTabInterface) newTab.newInstance();
  tabInterface.setRootController(this);
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is necessary since I don't know the name of the class I need to instantiate (`title` is determined elsewhere).

The problem I'm having is that, within the new class, I need access to `rootController` immediately.  I have a method within the class that allows me to pass the `rootController` reference, as seen in my above code.

Normally, I would pass `rootController` to the constructor when instantiating the class, but I don't know how to pass a parameter to the constructor in the `newInstance()` call above.

**EDIT**: To be clear, the code above is in my main class, used to instantiate a new FXML controller (newTab).

Comment: The correct answer is to invoke the appropriate constructor by reflection (as in P.J.Meisch's answer below). But just to note, assuming this is a controller associated with an FXML file, that the `initialize()` method is not invoked until `FXMLLoader.load()` is called, so your code above will achieve the aim of setting the root controller "between the constructor and initialize()".

Comment: @James_D The code I posted is NOT actually part of the FXMLs controller.  My FXML is loaded by the controller that contains the `setRootController` method.

Comment: I meant that the controller you were instantiating was the controller for an FXML file, but I was assuming you were loading the FXML later (not in the controller's constructor).  You could always load the FXML in the ` setRootController` method as a workaround/hack, but the correct answer is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your `newTab` object you can call `getConstructor(Class<?>...)`with the types of your constructor to get a reference to that constructor with the desired args.

Then you can call this constructor's `newInstance(Object...)`method to call the constructor with arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @P.J.Meisch.  Could you please elaborate a little?  If I don't know the name of the object I'm instantiating, I therefore wouldn't know the type of the constructor in order to call it, right?

I did edit my question to make it clear where I'm trying to call this from.

Comment: @Zephyr The `getConstructor` method is a method of `Class`. So you do `newTab.getConstructor(...).newInstance(this)` to reflectively pass `this` to the constructor. It's still all reflection, you don't need to know the class name. Just read the relevant Javadocs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @James_D.  I guess the part I'm getting so confused by is the code that is omitted in the examples I'm finding `(...)`.  The rest of it makes sense to me, but I'm not sure what `getConstructor()` is looking for in terms of parameters.  I've been reading through the Javadocs on it and just see `Class<?>...` with omitted code again.

Comment: The type(s) of the parameters for the constructor you are trying to retrieve. The [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) say "The parameterTypes parameter is an array of Class objects that identify the constructor's formal parameter types, in declared order." Not sure I can make it any clearer than that.

Comment: E.g. if you had a constructor with a single parameter of type `RootController`, then you would do `newTab.getConstructor(RootController.class).newInstance(this)`, assuming of course `this` is an instance of `RootController`.

Comment: Beautiful, @James_D!  That did the trick for me.  And better, I think I understand what's happening now.  In the future, if I have a constructor that accepts more than one parameter, do I just add them all in the `getConstructor()` method?  Eg: `newTab.getConstructor(RootController.class, String.class).newInstance(this)`?

Comment: thanks to anybody who tooke the time to elaborate on my short answer!